# prove that $(\hat{\beta}-\beta)'(X'X)^{-1}(\hat{\beta}-\beta)$ and SSE are independent

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

We have 
$$(\hat{\beta}-\beta)'(X'X)^{-1}(\hat{\beta}-\beta)$$
and
SSE $=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{y_{i}}-y_{i})^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^{2}-\hat{\beta'}X'y$
and I have to prove that these 2 quantities are independent.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379419/proving-that-hat-beta-beta-x-x-hat-beta-beta-is-independe.